# Write to last cell in named range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been having a look online/here and everything I can find relates only to full sheet, not to a range as part of that sheet.

I have a code that will take a named range "ARange", and search for any occurrence of "AValue"
If "AValue" is not in range, then it will extend the range to allow room to insert "AValue"

The problem I am running into is that after I extend the range, I'm not sure how to insert "AValue" into the last cell of the range.  This could be accomplished with another For Each Cell in ARange, which I'll turn to as a last resort.

Just a note.  ARange is just a sample name.  I want to be able to do this with several different ranges.  All 1 column wide.  some will start from Row 1, some Row 2, Some row 20, etc.

Is there any simple way to express the following so it works?

```
LastCell("ARange").Value = TextBox1.Value
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *named range* has been defined with a *Refers to:* that uses a formula like,

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A, 1)
```

... or the non-volatile equivalent of,

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz", Sheet1!$A:$A))       ◄ for text
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH(1e99, Sheet1!$A:$A))        ◄ for numbers
```

... then you just need to set the value in the first blank cell below the range and once the value is set the range's *Refers to: will adjust to encompass it.

```
With Range("my_Named_Range")
    .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(1) = "abc"
End With
```

As soon as the value is set, *my_Named_Range* extends to include it.

**EDIT:**

With *my_Named_Range_2* defined with a *Refers to:* (Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager) of,

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1, , MATCH("zzz", Sheet1!$1:$1))
```

... the code snippet provided above should be modified to,

```
With Range("my_Named_Range_2")
    .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1) = "abc"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped looks brilliant! I don't quite understand the refers to defining option, but I'll have a look.  

Is there a way to take the offset and apply it to a horizontal range instead? IE: A1:G1 - Set value of H1 as "ABC"

Comment: @User123456798 - I've added a snippet for a horizontally oriented named range to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that **ARange** is only one column wide:

```
Sub xTendIt()
    Dim ARange As Range, AValue As String
    '
    'this is an example
    '

    AValue = "X"
    Set ARange = Range("B9:B23")
    '
    'this is a general extender
    '
    Set ARange = ARange.Resize(ARange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    ARange(ARange.Count) = AValue
End Sub
```

or use *TextBox1.Value*